# Abstract class where child defines this variables

Tags: typescript

I'd like to use a TypeScript `abstract class` and have the implementation be forced to define functions / variables within the class it can use.

```
abstract class Animal {
  sound: string;
  speak() {
    console.log(this.sound);
  }
}

class Cat extends Animal {
  sound = 'meow';
}

const c = new Cat()
c.speak()
```

`sound` should be a required property of `Cat` and will also inherit `speak` from Animal.

Is something like this possible?

Yes, I need `abstract class` even though it's not apparent in this example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define abstract attribute `abstract sound: string` in Animal so Cat will have to implement it:

```js
abstract class Animal {
  abstract sound: string;
  speak() {
    console.log(this.sound);
  }
}
```

[example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=abstract%20class%20Animal%20%7B%0A%20%20abstract%20sound%3A%20string%3B%0A%20%20speak()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20console.log(this.sound)%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0A%20class%20Cat%20extends%20Animal%20%7B%0A%20%20%2F%2F%20sound%20%3D%20'meow'%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aconst%20c%20%3D%20new%20Cat()%0Ac.speak())

Answer (score -1):

You can add `abstract` to the property and it will allow that to be defined in the inhereted class.

```
abstract class Animal {
  abstract sound: string;
  speak() {
    console.log(this.sound);
  }
}

class Cat extends Animal {
  sound = 'meow';
}

const c = new Cat()
c.speak()
```